# Subclass of class that inherits from enable_shared_from_this returning shared_ptr of self

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is anyway to do something like this pseudo code:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<self_t> getPtr(){
            return std::static_pointer_cast<self_t>(shared_from_this());
        }
};

class B : public A {
    std::vector<A> container;

    std::shared_ptr<self_t> addChild(A child){
        container.push_back(child);
        return getPtr();
    }
};

class C : public B {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<self_t> doSomething(){
            // something
            return getPtr();
        }
};

int main(){
    A obja = new A();
    C obj = new C();
    obj->addChild(obja)->doSomething()
}
```

My goal is that an object represents a view (as in the V in MVC), and for methods to be able to return itself for chained calling. Eg: `->setTop(0)->addChild(child1)->setBottom(0)`.

I've read that it may be more approachable to do something like overloading the `<<` operator, but I don't see that working to well or looking very pretty.

One thought I had was to make a macro called `VIEW(name,parent)` that would use templates to expand out, but I had issue with self-refferental default template arguments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-- edit --

In a nut shell, I'm hoping to have a base class inherit from `enable_shared_from_this`. The base class would have a method such as `doSomething` that returns the shared pointer. When a derived class inherits from the base class, I want the `doSomething` method to return a shared pointer to the derived class. I want to be able to do this without overriding `doSomething` in the derived class.

Comment: Are you in essence are asking how to implement `self_t`?

Comment: Yes. Or a way to get this to work without each derived class having to create two classes.

Comment: I do not quite understand why to return `shared_ptr` instead of raw pointer?

Comment: @Slava, as long as you still using the object and there is a new pointer to it, you don't want reference count reaching 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of concept would be covered by extension methods which exist outside a class definition, do not violate the class permissions but can be called like a method... which exists in C# but not currently in C++. The code in C# looks like this:

```
// c# syntax
namespace MyBaseExtensions {
    public static class MyBaseExt {
        public static shared_ptr<T> getPtr<T>(this T self) where T : MyBase 
        {
            return static_pointer_cast<T>(self.shared_from_this());
        }
    }
}
```

This allows for operator chaining because each inheritance of a class line MyBase would have its own definition of the function because the function is not an inherited method but instead applied directly to each related type.

The argument against is that extensions pollute the object with often unneeded functionality and that a standalone template function will do the same thing. The issue is that with that logic:

```
int main(){
    A obja = new A();
    C obj = new C();
    obj->getPtr()->addChild(obja)->doSomething()
}
```

ends up looking like

```
int main(){
    A obja = new A();
    C obj = new C();
    doSomething(addChild(getPtr(obj),obja)); //eyeroll.
}
```

and you would still be declaring the template functions such like

```
// C++ syntax
namespace MyBaseExtensions {
    template<typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> getPtr<T>(T self)
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(self->shared_from_this());
    }
}
```

As for a simple internal way of applying a template uniquely to each derived type, I am not sure of any. The reason for this is that the functionality you want is not method inheritance but that each future class inherits a template which it automatically specializes(and of which the resulting method is either not inherited or hidden.) For that purpose C++ classes would need to have non-inherited specialized public methods, which are not covered by the current access permissions public, private, and protected or template capabilities.

I would be overjoyed to find a nice way to pull off operator chaining.

And since I have gone and wasted your time I made an attempt at this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// 0 argument, creates an overload method (and hides parent class method)
//           from template method func_name
// template method specialization of a parent method does not work
//      so we use C++11 automatic type deduction to figure the      
//         template return type and return what the template returns
#define FUNC_DEF_0(base, cur, func_name) \
    auto func_name() \
            -> decltype(base().func_name<cur>()) { \
        return base::func_name<cur>(); \
    }

// 1 argument
#define FUNC_DEF_1(base, cur, func_name, arg1_t) \
    auto func_name(arg1_t param1) \
            -> decltype(base().func_name<cur>(param1)) { \
        return base::func_name<cur>(param1); \
    }

// class A
// add to class to hide class A methods
#define HIDE_A(current) \
    FUNC_DEF_0(A, current, getPtr)

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    template<typename _T = A>
    std::shared_ptr<_T> getPtr(){
        return std::static_pointer_cast<_T>(shared_from_this());
    }
};


// class B
// add to class to hide class B methods with new methods
#define HIDE_B(current) \
    HIDE_A(current) \
    FUNC_DEF_1(B, current, addChild, A)

class B : public A {
public:
    std::vector<A> container;

    template<typename _T = B>
    std::shared_ptr<_T> addChild(A child){
        container.push_back(child);
        return A::getPtr<_T>();
    }

    HIDE_A(B); // hide A methods with B specialized methods

    // Example method hiding
    // auto getPtr() -> decltype(A().getPtr<B>()) {
    //     return base::getPtr<B>();
    // }
};


// class C
// add to class to hide class C methods
#define HIDE_C(current) \
    HIDE_B(current) \
    FUNC_DEF_0(C, current, doSomething)

class C : public B {
public:
    template<typename _T = C>
    std::shared_ptr<_T> doSomething(){
        // something
        return A::getPtr<_T>();
    }
    HIDE_B(C); // hide B methods
};

int main() {
    auto obja = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto obj = std::make_shared<C>();
    obj->addChild(*obja)->doSomething();
}
```

Edit: Fixed attempt. Compiles for me.

```
class A;

struct virtual_enable_shared_from_this_base :
    std::enable_shared_from_this<virtual_enable_shared_from_this_base> {
    virtual ~virtual_enable_shared_from_this_base() {}
};

#define HIDE_AMix(type) \
    using type::getPtr;

template<typename _T>
class AMix : public virtual virtual_enable_shared_from_this_base {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<_T> getPtr() {
        auto sptr = shared_from_this();
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<_T>(sptr);
    }
};

#define HIDE_BMix(type) \
    HIDE_AMix(type) \
    using type::addChild;

template<typename _T>
class BMix : public AMix<_T>{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> container;

    std::shared_ptr<_T> addChild(A* child){
        container.push_back(child->getPtr());
        return getPtr();
    }
};

#define HIDE_CMix(type) \
    HIDE_BMix(type) \
    using type::addChild;

template<typename _T>
class CMix : public BMix<_T>{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<_T> doSomething(){
        // something
        return getPtr();
    }
};


class A : public AMix<A> {
public:

};

class B : public A, public BMix<B> {
public:
    HIDE_AMix(BMix<B>);
    //using BMix<B>::getPtr;
    //using BMix<B>::addChild;
};

class C : public B, public CMix<C> {
public:
    HIDE_BMix(CMix<C>);
    //using CMix<C>::getPtr;
    //using CMix<C>::addChild;
    //using CMix<C>::doSomething;
};

int main() {
    auto obja = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto obj = std::make_shared<C>();
    obja->getPtr();
    obj->addChild(obja.get())->doSomething();
}
```

Edit2: Here is another version from fiddling around with templates.

Comment: I tried your sample code and was unable to compile it. http://pastebin.com/mNuMpSS5 Am I missing something?

Comment: My bad. I thought since the pre-processed file seemed correct syntax-wise it would work, it seems like there are some weird restrictions on trailing type deduction. The other option would be to just do away with the decltype and use shared_ptr<current> instead in the macro constructed function.

Comment: I dig it, thanks! Pending any other response between now and the next few days, I'll be accepting your answer for the bounty. Thanks again!

Comment: I liked the first version better and implemented that one. I didn't want subclasses to have to separate their logic into two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you may be trying to accomplish (though I'm not sure I 100% understood your requirements or reasoning for this design).  Hope it helps...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class MyBase;
typedef std::shared_ptr<MyBase> MyBaseSharedPtr;

class MyBase : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyBase> {
        public:
                MyBaseSharedPtr getPtr() { return shared_from_this(); }
                virtual MyBaseSharedPtr doSomething() { return getPtr(); };
                virtual MyBaseSharedPtr addChild(MyBaseSharedPtr child) { return getPtr(); };
};

class MyDerived1 : public MyBase {
        private:
                std::vector<MyBaseSharedPtr> container;
        public:
                MyBaseSharedPtr addChild(MyBaseSharedPtr child) {
                        container.push_back(child);
                        std::cout << "class MyDerived1: adding child\n";
                        return getPtr();
                };

                virtual MyBaseSharedPtr  doSomething() {
                        std::cout << "class MyDerived1: doing something\n";
                        return getPtr();
                }
};

class MyDerived2 : public MyDerived1 {
        public:
                MyBaseSharedPtr doSomething() {
                        std::cout << "class MyDerived2: doing something\n";
                        return getPtr();
                }
};

int main(void ) {
        MyBaseSharedPtr myBase = std::make_shared<MyBase>();
        MyBaseSharedPtr myDerived2 = std::make_shared<MyDerived2>();
        myDerived2->addChild(myBase)->doSomething();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea is that `MyBase` would have only `addChild` and no `doSomething`, and `MyDerived1` would have the `doSomething` and inherit `addChild`, but the result of `addChild` would return a `std::shared_ptr<MyDerived1>`. I don't want to have to overload `addChild` in `MyDerived1`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I just can't think of a good way to make it work exactly like you suggest.  In my very humble opinion, you might consider going back to the drawing board and rework your OO design.  But I'll be curious to see what others come up with.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm 100% open to suggestions on my design decision and if I find that it suits my purposes, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename _T>
shared_ptr<_T> allocate()
{
    shared_ptr<_T> ptr(new _T);
    // this may need to be changed to 
    // something like (*typename ptr.get()).weak_this
    // if the compiler won't accept a duck-typed _T::weak_this
    ptr.get()->weak_this = weak_ptr<_T>(ptr);
    return ptr;
}

class A
{
    weak_ptr<A> weak_this;
    friend shared_ptr<A> allocate<A>();

    public:
        shared_ptr<A> getPtr(){return weak_this.lock();}
        shared_ptr<A> doSomething()
        {
            // do something
            return getPtr();
        }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand your code or how this applies to my question, sorry. Can you show an example where a class extends from class `A` and `doSomething` would return a `shared_ptr` to the derived class without overriding `doSomething`?

Comment: @Kyle, I was showing how to implement something which can both use shared_ptr and allow for chaining of calls. There is no way to do what request after the edit. Simply because if B inherits from A, then shared_ptr<B> does not inherit from shared_ptr<A>. This is not a limitation of shared_ptr itself, but rather of templates. Here's why: return type is determined at compile time.  And you want the return type to match the run-time type. But at compile time the run-time type is not yet known. You can do something like this with a visitor, but visitor requires knowing all types ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, if what you really want is to be able to extend functionality without exploding multiple inheritance hierarchies and without overwriting each method everywhere, you could try composed functionality with templates. Something like this:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
};

template <class Parent>
struct A : Parent {
    std::list<Parent*> children;

    A* addChild(Parent* child) {
        children.push_back(child);
        return this;
    }
};

template <class Parent>
struct B : Parent {
    B* doSomething() {
        std::cout << "Something" << std::endl;
        return this;
    }
};

int main(){
    typedef A< B<Base> > Composed;
    Composed a;
    Composed b;
    a.addChild(&b)->doSomething();
}
```

Note, however, that this has the restriction that forces a **use order** based on the order you compose the "functionality" (classes). 
That is, in this example, you can't do:

```
a.doSomething()->addChild(&b); //ERROR! B is not a A
```

But this would work if you declare:

```
typedef B< A<Base> > Composed; //Note the order of B and A
```

I don't know if it suits your needs.

Hope this helps, at least, to enable you to think the problem in a different way.